# Undefined symbol when defined outside class, works when defined inside class

Tags: c++, undefined-reference, undefined-symbol

I'm somewhat new to C++ and am trying to understand the syntax and its behaviour. In particular, after quite a bit of googling and research, I was unable to find out why the following code won't compile:

```
class base {
public:
    base (const int);
};

class child: base {
public:
    child (const int);
};

child::child(const int num) : base(num) {}
```

but this will:

```
class base {
public:
    base (const int);
};

class child : base {
public:
    child (const int num) : base(num) {};
};
```

In the above case the linker fails with:

> Undefined symbol `base::base(int)`

I feel like I'm making a very stupid mistake but the compiler's errors are completely unhelpful.

Comment: Won't compile or won't link? Both snippets compile, none link, since the constructor in `base` is not defined. Post the error you're getting.

Comment: There should not be a `;` after the function definition block (`{};`) in both codes.

Comment: @tmlen that's not the issue, as `;` is treated like an empty statement.

Comment: Include the actual errors so that someone can help you.

Comment: @b4hand "Undefined symbol `base::base(int)`" in the above snippet. He's right, the compiler error doesn't help at all since `base::base(int)` is also undefined in the second snippet.

Comment: please paste the whole program.

Comment: @vsoftco Compiles and links successfully for me: http://ideone.com/5sc3NV.

Comment: @zenith try defining a class of type `child`. You only declare it, so the linker doesn't need to link any object code. And if you move your `child` constructor outside the class declaration, it won't link anymore.

Comment: @zenith I think when you declare it outside, the compiler generates object code for the constructor even if you don't use the class in `main`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is telling you exactly what the problem is. You must define a constuctor for `base` if you invoke it, and you are invoking it from the derived class `child`.

Try adding this to your code:

```
base::base(const int num) {}
```

This ignores the given argument, but at least your code will compile.

I would probably remove the declaration for the `base` constructor and not pass any value to it from the `child` class unless it was actually used.

In the second case, the constructor is inline and never invoked so the compiler does not need to generate code for it, but if you try to actually construct a `child` object, you will get the same linker error.

The reason inline code is not generated is because you have no invoking call site. The whole purpose behind declaring code inline is so that it is *inlined* at the call site. Thus the compiler defers code generation for all inline code until it is actually called.

Comment: I think your last two paragraphs best answer the question as they explain why there's no error when the constructor is defined inside the class (and not instantiated).

Answer (score 2):

When you define the constructor within the class, the compiler doesn't actually look for the base class constructor until you try to actually instantiate a member of the class. Once you do that (via e.g. `child a(5);`), you will get the same error as above, [see here](http://ideone.com/yHWIUX). When you defined the constructor outside the class, though, it was attempting to link it even without the instantiation, resulting in the error even without `child a(5);`.